# How to uninstall software package in single user mode in Solaris 11

Tags: unix, solaris

I accidentally installed a software package which keeps my Solaris from booting up. Upon entering single user mode, I ran:

```
pkg uninstall system/install/media/internal
```

However, it fails and says `pkg: No image rooted at '/'`

Any suggestion on how to uninstall the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you see indicates that the image has been corrupted or otherwise unexpectedly modified or the files and directories that pkg(1) uses to identify an "image" are missing.

Specifically, it appears that either the /var/pkg directory, or the /var/pkg/pkg5.image file is missing.  As a result, the pkg command can't find an image to operate on.  (See pkg(5) for a definition of what an image is).

If /var has been moved to a separate filesystem, that's not a supported configuration for Solaris 11, for this reason, and many others.